# Location for install.rdf

Tags: selenium, plugins, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to write a plug-in for selenium UI and following [this](http://adam.goucher.ca/?p=1331) tutorial. Below is an excerpt from this.

> First, what you need is an ‘install.rdf’ file and is located in the
>   root dir of your workspace

I am not sure what is root directory of workspace here mean. So I have firefox and selenium installed on my computer. Where exactly should I create this install.rdf

Comment: Looking at the tutorial linked, the _workspace_ is probably just a folder on your disk where you will have to place all the files. The install.rdf file sample xml is provided immediately after the above comment.

Comment: Thanks @Faiz. That's what I thought too but somehow selenium needs to know the location where it should load the plug-in and I don't see any option of how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

The root directory mentioned here is the root directory of the IDE source code. You can download IDE src code from location given below and put the install.rdf in the root.

[Selenium IDE src code](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/ide/)

Once you have made changes to the plugin src as per your needs. You can build it and install the .xpi hence built to your firefox instance like a regular extension and test it.